# Unexpected behavior with ```height: 100vh``` and white margin at the bottom of the page

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

So I have a webpage, whose structure at its core is:

```
<div id="left_container">
   <!-- lots of content here -->
</div>
<div id="right_container">
   <!-- lots of content here too -->
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#left_container {
    width: 80%;
}

#right_container {
    width: 19.5%;
    clear: both;
    display: inline-block;
    height: calc(100vh - 82px);
}
```

It looks like this:
[image]

As you can see, on the bottom of the page, there's this white space (you can see it clearly where the background color ends on the right side) and I don't understand where it's coming from. I'd like the right div to extend all the way to the bottom of the page, whereas now it almost looks like there a bottom margin, which there isn't.

Second point: you might be wondering why I have `height: calc(100vh - 82px);` on the right container: that was through trial and error. If I only set it to `100vh`, a scrollbar appears as if the page was longer than it actually is. It looks like this:

[image]

I'm not sure why it does this, as to my understanding `100vh` means 100% of the page height.

Does anybody know a possible solution to these?

---

Here's the full html for the page: https://pastebin.com/j5QkGhBy (I took the html after it was rendered, as it's a Django template, so it contains dynamic content. This should give you an idea of how the whole structure looks). Here's the full CSS too: https://pastebin.com/ZYCiga1K

Answer (score 0):

You could use grid design the layout of the container.

HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Page title</title>
        <link href="css/main.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div id="left_container">
                <!-- lots of content here -->
             </div>
             <div id="right_container">
                <!-- lots of content here too -->
             </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```css
* {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

html, body, .container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 80% 20%;
    grid-template-rows: auto;
}

#left_container {
    background-color: red;
}

#right_container {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Comment: I think we might be on the right track. But now it looks like this: https://i.imgur.com/QVG5jF4.png I don't understand where all that lateral margin is coming from. Plus we still have that scrollbar

Comment: You have to upload your colors css aswell for me to see what's up

Comment: One thing I noticed is that, if I add ```position: absolute``` to my ```.container``` CSS, and then I specify numbers for ```grid-template-columns``` that add up to more than 100%, I can get it looking something like this: https://i.imgur.com/HVyE4KD.png (don't pay attention to the fact that there's a different colorset, everything else is the same) -- notice the scrollbar is still there, but why is it working for percentages that add up to >100%?

Comment: I don't have the full web solution so it's hard to fix it, because it looks different on my end. What you could do, if you wanted to remove the scroll bar, is set html's and body's width and height to 100% in css, and then in body's css type: overflow-y: hidden.

Comment: Yeah I'm sorry about that, not really able to share the full page at this point, but I noticed that the solution I mentioned above doesn't work if I look at the page on another -- smaller -- screen: in this case, the thing doesn't fit horizontally and a scrollbar appears. With ```position:absolute``` the container isn't centered either if I zoom in or out. The solution in your post is clearly the correct one; I just need to figure out why there's so much margin at the sides

Comment: solved! All I had to do was add ```max-width: 100%``` to ```.container```. Now I still have to fix the scrollbar issue though: just adding ```overflow-y: hidden``` to ```body``` won't cut it because when I do need the scrollbar, say I zoom in, then it won't appear. So another fix is in order